# How to show full name instead of merchant id in view "Manage merchant id"

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**view section**

```
  <div class="content-header-left col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
     <h3 class="content-header-title mb-0 font-14"> 
         <a href="#"> 
             <i class="close icon-arrow-left font-16 px-50 float-left></i>
        </a> Manage <?php echo $merchantId; ?>
    </h3>

   //we have to replace mechantId with fullname in database
  </div>
```

**function in controller**

```
class SubMerchantController extends AppController { 
    public $permission_dashboard=array();
    public $plugin = null;
    public $modelClass = 'SubMerchant';
    public $lang="admin";  
    public $merchantId="";  
    public $imageFolder="merchants";


    public $module="Multiple Pickup Points";  

    public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Time','Text'); 

    public function initialize()
    {

        parent::initialize(); 
        $this->loadModel('Merchants.SubMerchant');
        $this->loadModel('Masters.CompanyType');
        $this->loadModel('Masters.Plan');
        $this->loadModel('UserContact');
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg', [ 'actions' => ['index'] ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Common');
        $this->loadComponent('Upload');


    }

    public function beforeRender(Event $event){ 
        $action=isset($this->request->params['action'])?$this->request->params['action']:"";
        $loginMerchant=$this->request->session()->read('Auth.FrontUser.id');

        if($action=="sortOrder" || $action=="view" || $action=="ajaxPlanData"){
            $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax'); 
        }elseif($loginMerchant!=""){
            $this->viewBuilder()->layout('merchantAfterLogin');    

        }else{
            $this->viewBuilder()->layout('adminAfterLogin');    

       }    
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event){

         $this->CommonAuthCheck();

         $merchantId=$this->request->query('merchant_id');
         //Login Merchant Check
          $loginMerchant=$this->request->session()->read('Auth.FrontUser.id');
         if($merchantId==""){
          $merchantId=$loginMerchant;
         }

         if($merchantId<=0){
          //$this->redirect('/');
          //exit;
         }

         $this->merchantId=$merchantId;
         $this->set('merchantId',$merchantId);

         $this->set('modelName', 'SubMerchant');
         $this->set('lang', 'admin');
         $this->set('module', $this->module);
         $this->set('pluginFolder', 'Merchants');
         $this->set('imageFolder', $this->imageFolder);


    }


    public function index(){ 
                $sort=isset($this->request->query['sort'])?$this->request->query['sort']:"";
                $direction=isset($this->request->query['direction'])?$this->request->query['direction']:"";


            $query = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('search', $this->{$this->modelClass}->filterParams(array_map('trim',$this->request->query))); 
            $this->paginate = array(                    
                        'limit' =>  $this->request->query('listing')!=""?$this->request->query('listing'):"10",
                        'fields'=>array('id','parent_id','full_name','email','brand_name','merchant_code','register_pincode','status','last_login','created','updated'),
                        'conditions'=>array('parent_id'=>$this->merchantId), 
                        'order'=>array($this->modelClass.'.full_name'=>'asc'),  
                    ); 
            $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;  

            $this->set('datas',$this->paginate($query));
            //debug($this->paginate($query));
            //exit;
            $searchArray=array(
            'status'=>(isset($this->request->data['status']) && $this->request->data['status'])?$this->request->data['status']:"",
            'full_name'=>(isset($this->request->data['full_name']) &&
                $this->request->data['full_name'])?$this->request->data['full_name']:"",
            'email'=>(isset($this->request->data['email']) && $this->request->data['email'])?$this->request->data['email']:"",
            'merchant_code'=>(isset($this->request->data['merchant_code']) &&
                $this->request->data['merchant_code'])?$this->request->data['merchant_code']:"",

            );

            $listHeadings=array(
                                'ID'=>array('field'=>'id','icon'=>SORT_ICON),
                                'Name'=>array('field'=>'full_name','icon'=>SORT_ICON),
                                'Email'=>array('field'=>'email','icon'=>SORT_ICON),
                                'Brand',
                                'Date'=>array('field'=>'created','icon'=>SORT_ICON),
                                ); 
   $this->set(compact('searchArray','listHeadings','sort','direction')); 
        }
```

**database table**

[phpmyadmin table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVkfJ.png)

Comment: It's very hard to read anything as code || text || error in this mess. Could you fix your post?

Comment: You don't really have to write your question as comment...

Comment: Can I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then please go back and edit your post? It's a hard-to-read mess currently. And please write your actual question outside the code section, not just as comments which might be easy to miss (and not just in the title either - the title should be a succinct summary off the issue, not the whole question!). This will greatly improve the chances of someone being able to help you, and reduce the chances of your question being downvoted and closed as un-answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic CakePHP:

**Interacting with Views**

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views

**Example:**

- function index() -> set data to -> index.ctp
- function view() -> set data to -> view.ctp

**Concat strings:**

- simple: `echo $name . ' ' . $surname;` // John Doe
- complex: ```echo sprintf('%s %s', $name, $surname); // John Doe

**Set data from controller:**

- $this->set('full_name', sprintf('%s %s', $name, $surname));

**Print full_name in view:**

- `echo $full_name`

**CakePHP way:**

```
$data = $this->Users->find()->first();
$this->set(compact($data));

// view:
echo $data->full_name
```